How do I group columns with R tidyr's complete() function?
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(alph = c("a", "b", "b"),
             nums = c("1", "2", "2"),
             vals = c("foo", "bar", "baz"),
             col = c("x", "y", "z"))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  alph  nums  vals  col
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     1     foo   x
2 b     2     bar   y
3 b     2     baz   z

Let's start with the df tibble shown above. I want to

group by alph, nums and vals
complete all possible combinations
then NA the remaining columns. The output would look like this:

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  alph  nums  vals  col
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     1     foo   x
2 a     2     foo   NA   
3 b     1     bar   NA
4 b     1     baz   NA
5 b     2     bar   y    
6 b     2     baz   z

Here's my attempt that does not work:
df %>% group_by(alph, nums) %>% complete(alph, nums, vals)

What's the correct way to do this? Should I use complete()'s nesting argument?

df |> complete(nesting(alph, vals), nums)? It sounds like you want all nums for each combination of alph/vals present in the data.

btw, complete() is in tidyr, not dplyr. (Both of which loaded with tidyverse)

@Jon Spring thank you, that works. Do you mind explaining why in an answer? I've updated the question to correct the issue you pointed out. Here's my final code df %>% complete(nesting(alph, vals), nums) %>% select(alph, nums, vals, col) %>% arrange(alph, nums, vals)

See ?complete: To find all unique combinations of x, y and z, including those not present in the data, supply each variable as a separate argument: expand(df, x, y, z) or complete(df, x, y, z).   To find only the combinations that occur in the data, use nesting: expand(df, nesting(x, y, z)).
You can combine the two forms. For example, expand(df, nesting(school_id, student_id), date) would produce a row for each present school-student combination for all possible dates.
